# Lightweight java lib for geo spatial search?

Tags: java, geospatial

My current need is quite simple. We have some geo location information , represented like (longitude, latitude, content). We need to search for locations that within X kilometres given a query location.

There are not many locations to query, I think they can be index in RAM.
Is there any simple Java lib for this need?  Thanks

Comment: Similar question at Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27569/java-data-structure-to-store-geographical-objects-and-retrieve-them-by-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). It has geo spatial search capabilities and can be embedded in you application as well.

Comment: I tested the Lucene spatial, it works but seems not as efficient as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

[JSI (Java Spatial Index)](http://jsi.sourceforge.net/) provides a relatively simple but fast R-Tree implementation in Java, however this is designed for planar coordinates.  I'm not sure how well it works with geospatial coordinates (for wrapping at the poles and at 180 degrees longitude).

[NASA Worldwind Java SDK](http://goworldwind.org/) includes an efficient implemenation of QuadTree that works well with geospatial coordinates.

I have benchmarked speed and time complexity for Insert and Query operations and both showed similar performance for up to 10,000 items.

I have not tried [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) spatial yet, but will give it a go now and see how well it compares in my little benchmark test.

Comment: @AlexWien I think it is "rectangle" (or "Sector") based although the API allows entries to be either kind. See [API Docs](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.3/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/util/BasicQuadTree.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) also has [spatial queries capabilities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html/ch09.html).

It's built on top of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) and it make it possible to index data via annotations and to retrieve them using full-text queries.